# Detecting Color of iPhone/iPad/iPod touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uidevice

Is there any way or hack to detect on what color (black / white) iPhone, iPad or iPod touch the iOS is installed?

I want to load corresponding UI skins in case of Black or White devices.

Comment: Not a good idea. With dark mode, users can choose these things

Comment: @AlexH At the time of asking I didn't saw dark mode coming almost 8 years later. :)

Comment: A lot has changed. Are you still working on whatever project this is?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's a private API to retrieve both the `DeviceColor` and the `DeviceEnclosureColor`.

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"deviceInfoForKey:");
if (![device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_deviceInfoForKey:");
}
if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"DeviceColor: %@ DeviceEnclosureColor: %@", [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceColor"], [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"]);
}
```

I've blogged about this and provide a sample app:

http://www.futuretap.com/blog/device-colors/

**Warning: As mentioned, this is a private API. Don't use this in App Store builds.**

Comment: Nice find! A minor suggestion: You should use `[NSObject -respondsToSelector:]`.  Your current logic may function incorrectly when iOS 8 is released.

Comment: This would still use the older `deviceInfoForKey:` on iOS 8.  I would just check both selectors and see which one it responds to.

Comment: @uchuugaka I didn't hide the fact it's private. But that's the only way to retrieve it. There are some use cases for private APIs nonetheless – inhouse enterprise apps for instance. Complain with Apple (you can dupe http://openradar.appspot.com/15209345), instead of downvoting my answer!

Comment: Aaron, you're right. I improved the code to be iOS version agnostic.

Comment: I down voted because you didn't call out the ramifications of private API use when suggesting private API use.

Comment: You are a genius. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 20):

The answer to the question is **NO** (as of now) and *personally* I don't think it's worth much, because what if the end-user uses a skin or an additional casing for his iPhone?

> I'd suggest to initially ask the user "Hey, what's the color of your phone?" and then do accordingly.

---

Additionally, a research provided me with this information, I'm not sure if it's **TRUE** or if is going to help you.

> The serial number is the key :)

If `aabccdddeef` is the serial number of the iPhone 4, `ee` represents the Color, (A4=black). I hope some of you here check this information with yours to see if this is true.

Comment: I have a black iPhone 4S & a white one... The second and third last digits of both of them are "TF"... (Serial numbers: "C39GJ***DTFC" and "C39GK***DTF9"). We need to keep looking.

Comment: Moreover, one cannot detect Serial number programmatically (at least by using the published API's). So the serial number approach is DoA.

Comment: Thanks for replies, I appreciate it. In "hack" I meant something like serial number check or similar. I do realize that there is no `[IUDevice deviceColor]` thing in current SDK. I'm doing my own research and keep you posted.

Answer (score 11):

Just my 2 cents worth - if anyone is looking for the iPhone 5c colors, the colors below are picked from the apple website.

Hope it is of use to anyone:-)

> iPhone 5c Colors:

```
Green
R   179
G   243
B   142
HEX #B3F38E

Blue
R   123
G   195
B   252
HEX #7BC3FC

Yellow
R   255
G   243
B   141
HEX #FFF38D

Red
R   252
G   132
B   142
HEX #FF848E

White
R   239
G   239
B   239
HEX #EFEFEF
```

Answer (score 8):

According to information sprinkled around the web, the color of the device is encoded in the serial number. [iFixit's blog](http://www.ifixit.com/blog/blog/2010/07/13/is-apple-silently-fixing-the-iphone-4-antenna-issue/) indicates that the third- and second-to-last positions hold the information: `xxxxxxxxCCx` For an iPhone 4, `A4` indicates black. No one seems to have the code for a white iPhone 4, which is strange. One [forum posting](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=12991171&postcount=9) indicates that it *might* be `DZ`. Everyone seems to be just parroting everyone else's information here.

Another site, [mydigitallife.com](http://www.mydigitallife.info/iphone-serial-number-secret-decode-color-size-production-year-and-week/), has an article listing the color codes for various older models. In some cases, the three positions have to be read together in order to determine the color. According to this site, *all* iPhone 3Gs models have `3N` in the color code position; `3NP` indicates "Black 16GB 3Gs", and `3NQ` indicates "White 16GB 3Gs". The original (2G) iPhone also uses all three positions to indicate size (there were no color options).

There are already a number of questions here on SO that will help you to get the device's serial number.

Answer (score 8):

For debugging purposes I compiled a more comprehensive list of of possible `deviceInfoForKey:` keys.

Interesting keys to note (for this question) are `DeviceRGBColor` `DeviceEnclosureRGBColor`. The values appear to be an integer that represent the RGB value in the form `0x00rrggbb`.

Here, for reference, are all the keys I found:

```
ActiveWirelessTechnology        
AirplaneMode        
assistant        
BasebandCertId        
BasebandChipId        
BasebandPostponementStatus        
BasebandStatus        
BatteryCurrentCapacity        
BatteryIsCharging        
BluetoothAddress        
BoardId        
BootNonce        
BuildVersion        
CertificateProductionStatus        
CertificateSecurityMode        
ChipID        
CompassCalibrationDictionary        
CPUArchitecture        
DeviceClass        
DeviceColor        
DeviceEnclosureColor        
DeviceEnclosureRGBColor        
DeviceName        
DeviceRGBColor        
DeviceSupportsFaceTime        
DeviceVariant        
DeviceVariantGuess        
DiagData        
dictation        
DiskUsage        
EffectiveProductionStatus        
EffectiveProductionStatusAp        
EffectiveProductionStatusSEP        
EffectiveSecurityMode        
EffectiveSecurityModeAp        
EffectiveSecurityModeSEP        
FirmwarePreflightInfo        
FirmwareVersion        
FrontFacingCameraHFRCapability        
HardwarePlatform        
HasSEP        
HWModelStr        
Image4Supported        
InternalBuild        
InverseDeviceID        
ipad        
MixAndMatchPrevention        
MLBSerialNumber        
MobileSubscriberCountryCode        
MobileSubscriberNetworkCode        
ModelNumber        
PartitionType        
PasswordProtected        
ProductName        
ProductType        
ProductVersion        
ProximitySensorCalibrationDictionary        
RearFacingCameraHFRCapability        
RegionCode        
RegionInfo        
SDIOManufacturerTuple        
SDIOProductInfo        
SerialNumber        
SIMTrayStatus        
SoftwareBehavior        
SoftwareBundleVersion        
SupportedDeviceFamilies        
SupportedKeyboards        
telephony        
UniqueChipID        
UniqueDeviceID        
UserAssignedDeviceName        
wifi        
WifiVendor
```

Comment: These all are private APIs

Comment: Yes, they are all private. As stated in the accepted answer `deviceInfoForKey:` is private. Therefor all these keys are too.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, no, there is no official way of getting this information. Apple clearly knows (look in iTunes when you sync), so they *could* make it available. Might be worth raising a [Radar](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).