# iPhone/iPad enclosure color programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Does anyone know if it's possible to know the color of the iPhone/iPad enclosure programmatically? I'd like to build an app that loads different UI whether the iPhone/iPad is black or white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I as know, you may be able to determine the color of the phone based off the serial number of the device as discussed here: [Detecting Color of iPhone/iPad/iPod touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipod-touch)

I think your best bet it is to show different models of the phone in different colors then ask the user to pick one.

Good luck.