# Detecting iPhone color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Recently Apple shows the new iPhones 5s and 5c this devices have to many colors, **white, pink, yello, blue, green, space grey, gold and silver**... wow is to many, but my question is:

I will to create an App with the possibility to detecting the color of the device to turn the UI in the specific color for that device.

Now I know your answer, **NO its NOT possible**, and give me a minus vote, but I ask to please  take a moment to ponder on **iTunes** with your device connected if is **iPhone** or **iPad**, because when you connect your device, iTunes is able to detect the color, and show on the device page the exactly color Black/White or **iPod** colors.

Someone know the method on **xcode objectiveC** to do that?

Or is only an ability for iTunes?

Found this tutorial for the UDID inside app, what think about that?

> http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/how-to-replace-the-udid/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipod-touch?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263640/detect-color-of-iphone-ipod?rq=1

Comment: here it is possible to assume that if i use this function [[UIDevice currentDevice] serialnumber] i can detecting the color, but i need to get all type of "serials color" right?

Comment: @Jhon I don't think you will be able to get values from serial numbers, for one you don't know what number does apple correspond to gold Vs silver. Its not documented anywhere in app docs and other sites have given some (not all) color codes that they think apply to iphone 4. Nothing for new iphone 5

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that iTunes finds all of the information based on the UDID the phone which is:

A UDID is a 40 character string of letters and numbers, sort of like a serial number, and      uniquely identifies a particular iOS device, including iPhones, iPads, and iPod touches. The alphanumeric code looks completely random to people, but it is actually based on various hardware characteristics. Like a serial number, each iOS device has a UDID that refers to only that specific device. You can see your own device's UDID by going into iTunes and clicking on your device's serial number on its sync screen.

[a link]http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/09/ask-ars-whats-the-big-deal-with-iphone-udids/

So maybe you might be able to find a way to extract this information?

Just an idea.

Comment: I know how can get UDID from iTunes, i think is a very hard to get UDID from the app I try to found a code to get the serial number, but working only on your device in a TestMode (Xcode Run on Device) i think is rejected from apple if I leave the code inside a final release.