# Is it possible to make an app work only on a gold iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to use Xcode configurations or some other method to target only a gold iPhone?

Comment: Are you serious? Who got such a golden iPhone?

Comment: Downvotes seem inappropriate here-- although the answer may be obvious to any seasoned iOS developer, this question is valid, on-topic, about programming, and not a duplicate.

Comment: @TaylorHalliday Do you mean the gold colored iPhone 5s?

Comment: Yes - on the grammar thing I was just messing around. But, yes. I was joking around with someone about how ridiculous it would be if you possibly make a app that only worked on a Gold iPhone 5S. Seemed like a funny concept. Even though I doubted it - decided to throw it out on SO to see if it was possible. Didn't mean to offend any devs by asking - just wondering if there was something that I wasn't thinking of.

Comment: Throwing it out there - How is this question down voted, but the link to the SO Q above this comment received so much positive attention. They get at the same technical Q - detecting cosmetics on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to detect iOS device colour programmatically via public APIs.
Still, you could use private ones.
According to @Ortwin Gentz's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch):

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"deviceInfoForKey:");
if (![device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_deviceInfoForKey:");
}
if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"DeviceColor: %@ DeviceEnclosureColor: %@", [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceColor"], [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"]);
}
```